# Wrap all ® characters in HTML document in <sup>®</sup> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, superscript

I have a document with many ® characters throughout. I need to make them all render in superscript. I am trying this but having no luck:

```
$('body:contains("®")').contents().each(function () {
    if (this.nodeType == 1) { //Look for only element Nodes
        $(this).html(function (_, oldValue) {
            return oldValue.replace(/®/g, "<sup>$&</sup>")
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a basic replace;

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/\u00AE/g, "<sup>&reg;</sup>"))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/4dnQL/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is performant or robust enough for production, but it seems to work in my limited test:

```
$(function () {
    var html = $('body').html();
    html = html.replace(/®/g, "<sup>®</sup>");
    $("body").html(html);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zphv6/

Basically grabs the body's HTML as a string, performs a regex search/replace, and replaces the body's HTML with the new string.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the character is placed into the HTML but it might be as simple as this -

```
$("body").children().each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\&reg;/g,"<sup>&reg;</sup>"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/363qC/